# Use guzzle and promise to create a mailchimp list

Tags: php, mailchimp, guzzle

Full code: https://github.com/kenpeter/test_guzzle

I try to create a mailchimp list with Guzzle, the http client.

When I am running `php create_list_memeber_update.php`

Error I got is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid resource type: array in /var/www/html/test/testme/test_guzzle/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php:116
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/test/testme/test_guzzle/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Request.php(53): GuzzleHttp\Psr7\stream_for(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/test/testme/test_guzzle/create_list_memeber_update.php(49): GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request->__construct('POST', Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri), Array, Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/test/testme/test_guzzle/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php on line 116
```

I think it is something to do with the headers

```
$headers = array(
  'User-Agent' => 'testing/1.0',
  'Accept'     => 'application/json'
);
```

Code for create_list_memeber_update.php:

```
<?php

// auto load
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

// opt
$option = array(
  'base_uri' => "https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/",
  'auth' => ['apikey', '292bae37c631ac3ba03ed0640b44e6c3'],
);

// client
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client($option);

// data for a new list
$data = array(
  "name" => "test_mailchimp",
  "contact" => array(
    "company" => "MailChimp",
    "address1" => "675 Ponce De Leon Ave NE",
    "address2" => "Suite 5000",
    "city" => "Atlanta",
    "state" => "GA",
    "zip" => "30308",
    "country" => "US",
    "phone" => "12345678",
  ),
  "permission_reminder" => "You're receiving this email because you signed up for updates.",
  "use_archive_bar" => true,
  "campaign_defaults" => array(
    "from_name" => "test",
    "from_email" => "test@test.com",
    "subject" => "test_subject",
    "language" => "en",
  ),
    "notify_on_subscribe" => "",
    "notify_on_unsubscribe" => "",
    "email_type_option" => true,
    "visibility" => "pub",
);

$headers = array(
  'User-Agent' => 'testing/1.0',
  'Accept'     => 'application/json'
);
$body = ['json' => $data];
$req_create_list = new Request('POST', 'lists', $headers, $body);

// promise
$promise = $client
  ->sendAsync($req_create_list)
  ->then(function ($res) {
    echo $res->getBody();
  });
$promise->wait();
```

Comment: you're passing an array to the function `stream_for` which is expecting either a resource or an object.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found and its working perfectly fine

```
    // format for mail chimp data


    --url 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches' \
    --user 'anystring:apikey' \
    --header 'content-type: application/json' \
    --data '{"operations" : [{"method" : "POST","path" : 
    "lists/624ea08019/members", "body": "
     {\"email_address\":\"freddie@mailchimp.com\", 
     \"status\":\"subscribed\"}"}, 
    //end format

    $userlist = array(format array data)      
    $auth = base64_encode('user:'.config('mailchimp.api_key'));
    //API URL
    $urll = "https://".config('mailchimp.data_center').".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches";
    //API authentication Header
    $headers = array(
        'Accept'     => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Basic '.$auth
    );
    $client = new Client();
    $req_Memeber = new Request('POST', $urll, $headers, $userlist);
    // promise
    $promise = $client->sendAsync($req_Memeber)->then(function ($res){
            echo "Synched";
        });
      $promise->wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are passing the $body value as array, however the Guzzle Request class expects the fourth parameter to be an object. Try using **json_encode** to fix that:

```
$config['auth']=['apikey',env('MAILCHIMP_API_KEY')];
$config['base_uri']=env('MAILCHIMP_API_URL');

$client = new Client($config);
$url = '3.0/lists/'.$listId.'/members';

$headers['content-type']='application/json';
$data=['email_address'=>$email,'status'=>'subscribed','segment'=>$segment];

$json = json_encode($data);
$request = new Request('POST', $url, $headers, $json);
```